# Python is throwing AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Can someone please help me fix this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'.
```

I am still learning. I am just trying to create a game named by "Alien Invasion " from book , but every time I am trying to keydown the SPACE it will throw

```
AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'.
```

I am not even what the error means other than that I am missing a request somewhere.

Any help and explanation of what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance. And sorry for there may be some Chinese in it, if it makes you uncomfortable , cause I'm from China.

**Here are my models:**

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from ship import  Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    #初始化pygame、设置和屏幕对象
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_hight))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invavsion")

    #设置背景色
    bg_color=(230,230,230)

    #创建一艘飞船
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    #创建一个用于存储子弹的编组
    bullets = Group()

    #开始游戏的主循环
    while True:
        #监视键盘和鼠标事件
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()
        gf.updata_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

run_game()
```

settings.py

```
class Settings():
    """存储《外星人入侵》的所有设置的类"""

    def __init__(self):
        """初始化游戏的设置"""
        #屏幕设置
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_hight = 700
        self.bg_color = (250,250,250)

        #飞船的位置
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

        #子弹设置
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys
from bullet import Bullet
import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """响应按键"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        #创建一颗子弹，并将其加入到编组bullets中
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """响应松开 """
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """响应按键和鼠标事件"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ship, screen, bullets, ai_settings)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                check_keyup_events(event,ship)


def updata_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """更新屏幕上的图像，并切换到新屏幕"""
    # 每次循环时都重绘屏幕
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    #在飞船和外星人后面重绘所有子弹
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

    ship.blitme()

    # 让最近绘制的屏幕可见
    pygame.display.flip()
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """初始化飞船并设置其初始位置"""
        self.screen=screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        #加载飞船图像并获取其外接矩形
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #将每艘新飞船放在屏幕底部中央
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        #在飞船的属性center中存储小数值
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        #移动标志
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """根据移动标志调整飞船的位置"""
        #更新飞船的center值，而不是rect
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        #根据self.centerx跟新的rect对象
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        """在指定位置绘制飞船"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """一个对飞船发射子弹的进行管理的类"""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """在飞船所处位置创建一个子弹对象"""
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        #在（0，0）处创建一个表示子弹移动的矩形，再设置正确的位置
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
                                ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.conterx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship = ship.rect.top

        #存储用小数表示的子弹位置
        self.y =float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        """向上移动子弹"""
        #更新表示子弹位置的小数值
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        #更新表示子弹的rect的位置
        self.rect.y = self.y


    def draw_bullet(self):
        """在屏幕上绘制子弹"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Comment: Unless you give a hint of which line of the above code is giving the error it is impossible to help. Well, more than a hint: which line is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is a `Ship` object is having it's `bullet_width` attribute accessed, which doesn't exist. It seems like you mixed up the order of some arguments, so that it thinks that a ship is an object that has a `bullet_width` attribute, like `Bullet()` or `Settings()`.

Ctrl+F for `.bullet_width`:

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bullet_width = 3
```

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
                                ai_settings.bullet_height)
```

It seems to be the second one. Ctrl+F for `Bullet(`

```
def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
```

OK, so now Ctrl+F for `check_keydown_events(`:

```
def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        check_keydown_events(event, ship, screen, bullets, ai_settings)
```

Ahah! You probably meant `check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)`, as a `ship` is being passed as `ai_settings`, which is causing the error.

---

When you get errors like these, you know that something is not what it says that it is. In this case, use a debugger and place a break point just before where it errors, and then inspect the objects. In any case, a handy `print('DEBUG:', everything_neccessary)` would have immediately showed you what the problem was:

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        print('DEBUG:', 'ai_settings', ai_settings)

# OUTPUT
DEBUG: ai_settings <Ship object at 0xxxx>
# That doesn't seem right! It should be a `<Settings object at 0xxxx>`
```

Comment: Sorry I am just still don't understand how to fix this error .....whether I am supposed to make  a change like  '' check_keydown_events(event, ship, screen, bullets, ai_settings) '' to '' check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)'' ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Ship object at least from the code above doesn't have a `bullet_width`. It looks like that's saved inside the `ai_settings`. Is the above the complete code? Or is there another location in your code where you may be trying to access `ship.bullet_width` when you really need to enter `ship.ai_settings.bullet_width` and that's throwing the error?

Answer (score -1):

I am also learning  python, there are 2 problems I find for you reference:
1. game_functions.py:
   a. updata is wrong, it should be update
   b. the order in check_keydown_events is wrong*(check_keydown_events(event, ship, screen, bullets, ai_settings)*,the right order is as follows:
   check_keydown_events(event,ai_setting,screen,ship,bullets)
2. alien_invasion.py
bg_color is repeated contrast to ship.py
(in other words,you have set the attribute"bg_color" in ship.py, there is no need to repeat it in alien_invasion.py)

Hope to help you~

Comment: I find the main problem maybe:                                                                                               bullet.py----self.rect=ship=ship.rect.top, need to delete center"ship"                    settings.py-----the attribute "hight" is not consistent with 'height'                      alien_invasion.py----change updata into update